# What Control can I use in WPF to emulate the Word Color Picker?

Tags: wpf, combobox

What Control can I use in WPF to emulate the Word Color Picker? In the WPF Ribbon, I think I have the RibbonGallery + `IsSharedColumnSizeScope` as shown in [Lester's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/using-ribbongallery-control). Can I do the same with a normal WPF `ComboBox`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your own. There is many examples and tutorials out there. But here is the one i used. [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ColorPicker2010.asp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ColorPicker2010.aspx)x